# Nginx configs for symfony3

Tags: php, nginx, symfony

I have some troubles with nginx.
I created new project on Symfony3. Config.php says, that everything is good. dev_app.php - too.
But when I try to open site without any other route, like sitename.com nginx returns 403 error.
When I try to start symfnoy server (bin/console server:start) It's forbidden too.
sitename.com:8000 returns me fail to opening this page.

site-available config is

```
upstream phpfcgi {
    server 127.0.0.1:8000;
}

server {
    listen 80;

    server_name localhost;
    root /home/staging/www/web;

    error_log /home/staging/logs/staging.error.log;
    access_log /home/staging/logs/staging.access.log;

    location / {
        index app.php;
        try_files $uri @rewriteapp;
    }

    location @rewriteapp {
        rewrite ^(.*)$ /app.php/$1 last;
    }

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server from upstream phpfcgi
    location ~ ^/(app|app_dev|config)\.php(/|$) {
        fastcgi_pass phpfcgi;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param  HTTPS off;
    }
}
```

I added new entity with crud, but any actions doesn't work.
I will be glad for any help. Thanks

Comment: Have you looked into nginx and PHP logs? Is your directory permissions set up properly?

Comment: Have you considered [reading the manual](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/configuration/web_server_configuration.html#nginx) ?

Comment: Yes, I read manual. This code doesn't work too. Logs are empty

Comment: is it possible that /app.php/$1 should be /app.php$1  ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add

```
rewrite ^/app\.php/?(.*)$ /$1 permanent;
```

in the `server` section before any `location` sections (after the `root /home/staging/www/web;` line, for example).